# Change file when creating a repository from template - Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a repository that I use as template, and it has some files that needs to be changed for each new repository. I have read the docs but couldn't find anything. How could I allow the user to update this variables when creating the repository, avoiding local changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According with the issue: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/26580 gitlab does not support parametrized projects.